# How to uniquely identify a monitor?

Tags: delphi, screen, multiple-monitors

I'm working on a project where I take screenshots of individual monitors (`TMonitor`) and stream their images through network (remote desktop viewing). Suppose a monitor is added/removed (which I can recognize this already), I need to synchronize *which* monitor this happened to. Because, suppose there's 3 monitors, indexes 0, 1, 2. Monitor 1 is removed. I don't want to automatically change index 2 to 1, I want it to maintain an ID at all times. Is there any property I can recognize in the `TMonitor` class (`Screen.Monitors[i]`) to uniquely identify it?

Comment: Does the Windows handle stay the same? If not, you could try working with the monitor resolution. There doesn't seem to be any kind of unique identifier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would say that the `Handle` property of `TMonitor` will be unique at all times.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A physical display has the same `HMONITOR` as long as it is part of the desktop.

Comment: HA! I can't believe I didn't see that, I was looking for `ID`